# Как устанавливать PECL?

Tags: apache, php

Привет.Хочу поставить memcache на Apache.Скачал файл с http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache
и нашел информацию что

> " Как и множество других PHP DLL
> расширений, инсталляция заключается в
> простом копировании DLL файла с PECL
> расширением в папку с расширениями
> «extension_dir» и их дальнейшей
> загрузкой в php.ini. Для примера,
> добавьте следующую строку в Ваш
> php.ini: extension=php_extname.dll
>
> После того, как все сделано,
> перезапустите веб сервер. "

В скачаном файле нету таких расширений.Что все файлы пихать в папку?

Comment: Судя по всему Вы скачали архив с исходными кодами на Си. Для того чтоб получить необходимый вам модуль с расширением *.dll вам необходимо их скомпилировать под Windows. О подробностях этого процесса читайте в документации.

Comment: мне советуют обратится сюда  http://pear.php.net/manual/ru/guide.users.commandline.beforeyoubegin.php 
Не вижу где тут можно скомпилировать.Может есть программка дополнительно?Неужели такой сервис не мог давать свои кода и в компилированом виде.Зло........

Comment: Глянь сюда: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511045/php-memcache-dll-for-php-5-3

Там есть ссылка на скомпиленую dll. Сказано, что работает под PHP 5.3.

Comment: 5.3.13 у меня и не работает.Конфликт версий...Ладно , не буду мучатся.Компилятор не подскажите и на этом думаю закончим.Всеравно хотел ради узучения.

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментария

---

Судя по всему, Вы скачали архив с исходными кодами на *Си*. Для того, чтобы получить необходимый вам модуль с расширением `*.dll`, вам необходимо их скомпилировать под *Windows*.

О подробностях этого процесса читайте в документации.